# Where is the exact location of res.partner in odoo?

Tags: odoo-10

I am trying to find the exact location of res.partner in odoo-10.

Comment: Just use your IDE search for this line.  `name = "res.partner"`. You will find it in base module. The location changes between odoo version and the source you downloaded the code from.

Comment: Just search for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it on either one of these paths.

`odoo/odoo/addons/base/res/res_partner.py`

**OR**

`odoo/addons/base/res/res_partner.py`

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In odoo10 the path of res.partner as follows

`home/test/workspace/Odoo_10/odoo-10.0/odoo/addons/base/res/res_partner.py`  in line number `130` class is define of res_partner.